# Get Linearlayout Childs from a Gridlayout Parent and clear them

Tags: android, android-layout

My issue as follow. I have 3 Linear Layouts into a Grid Layout.

Into each linear layout there are 3 ImageViews, so 9 in total. Please see xml below:

```
 <GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:rowCount="3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    //Line 1----------

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shield00"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="25dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:onClick="drop"
            android:scaleX="2.0"
            android:scaleY="2.0"
            android:tag="0" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shield01"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="9dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="25dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:onClick="drop"
            android:scaleX="2.0"
            android:scaleY="2.0"
            android:tag="1" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shield02"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="-1dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="25dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:onClick="drop"
            android:scaleX="2.0"
            android:scaleY="2.0"
            android:tag="2" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    //Line 2--------------

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shield10"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="25dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:onClick="drop"
            android:scaleX="2.0"
            android:scaleY="2.0"
            android:tag="3" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shield11"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="9dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="25dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:onClick="drop"
            android:scaleX="2.0"
            android:scaleY="2.0"
            android:tag="4" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shield20"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="25dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:onClick="drop"
            android:scaleX="2.0"
            android:scaleY="2.0"
            android:tag="5" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shield12"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="-1dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="25dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:onClick="drop"
            android:scaleX="2.0"
            android:scaleY="2.0"
            android:tag="6" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shield21"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="9dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="25dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:onClick="drop"
            android:scaleX="2.0"
            android:scaleY="2.0"
            android:tag="7" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shield22"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="-1dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:onClick="drop"
            android:scaleX="2.0"
            android:scaleY="2.0"
            android:tag="8" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>


</GridLayout>
```

The point is, I want to clean pics on ImageViews once the game is finished (this app is for a game).

I tryed to get Linear Layouts as childs from Grid Layoutand then getting each ImageViews as child from each Linear Layout. It didn´t work, code below:

```
public void restart(View view){

        GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
        clean(gridLayout);

    }


    //Clean ImageViews
    public void clean(GridLayout gridLayout){

        for(int i=0; i<gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) gridLayout.getChildAt(i);

            for(int j=0; j<linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
                ((ImageView) linearLayout.getChildAt(j)).setImageResource(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

As debugger indicates me, the crash appears on "((ImageView) linearLayout.getChildAt(j)).setImageResource(0);" line.

In addition, I already used "removeAllViews()" method. It deletes all pics but doesn´t allow to drop them again when a new game is started (unless app is restarted what doesn´t work for me).

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having 2 mistakes here:

**1:**

in second `loop`,

replace **i++**, with **j++**.

`for(int j=0; j<linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++){}`,

you just replace this

`for(int j=0; j<linearLayout.getChildCount(); j++){}`,

**2:**

You are traversing loop inside LinearLayout which contains ImageView as well as Space too. we you have to check childView's class-type.

For that you can use `instanceof` keyword.

you just replace with this this code.

```
//Clean ImageViews
    public void clean(GridLayout gridLayout){

        for(int i=0; i<gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) gridLayout.getChildAt(i);

            for(int j=0; j<linearLayout.getChildCount(); j++){
                Object obj = linearLayout.getChildAt(j);
                if (obj instanceof ImageView) {
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) linearLayout.getChildAt(j);
                    imageView.setImageResource(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good find, the i++ in the second loop

Comment: @Denny , Thanks.. happy coding... :-)

Comment: @Rumit - It works perfectly, thank you so much Rumit ;)

Comment: @Rumit Done! I never knew that, I´m a newbie, sorry =D

Comment: @isaac_sro Not to worry. Thanks bro. finally happy coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to cast every child layout in your second for-loop to an ImageView which is wrong because some child elements are of type 'Space'.

Try adding this in your second for loop to check if the view is an ImageView

```
if (view instanceof ImageView) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
```

For next time, also include the stack track in your question

Comment: Works! Thank you Denny ;)